# WCF Shared Library: Create updateable endpoint

Tags: c#, wcf

I developed a library that uses WCF to send data to and retrieve data from SAP QM. Numerous applications in our company use this library to store and retrieve data from QM.

Currently, the endpoint address is hard-coded into the library. I would like to move it out of the code. What is the recommended way of storing the endpoint address so that it can be updated/changed in the future without having to recompile the library or the applications that use this library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want it to be hard-coded in the library, you can define the endpoint address in the clients configuration file.

But since you have multiple internal applications that uses your endpoint, it would be a better approach to store the endpoint address in a centralized configuration which is accessible by each application. This could either be a shared database, or another service.

Then you have the possibility to change the endpoint address at any time.